# How to select an image from a database in SQLite 3 in python and display it in an image box

Tags: python, image, sqlite, glob

In the following function, an image should be selected from a table of images in a database. The problem is when the interpreter in PyCharm executes this code, the execution is crashed and stops with the following line printed on the terminal.

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

This is the function code:

```
def readMatchesImageFunction(p, m, imageID):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("OVSdatabase.db")
    readCursor = conn.cursor()
    matchesImage = readCursor.execute(""" SELECT fingerprint FROM RegisteredFingerprints WHERE fingerprintID = imageID """)
    resultImage = numpy.asarray(bytearray(matchesImage[1]), dtype="unit8")
    viewImage = cv2.imdecode(resultImage, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    p.QPixmap(viewImage)
    im.setPixmap(p)
```

Comment: `readCursor.execute()` doesn't return result of the query. You have to call `readCursor.fetchone()` or `readCursor.fetchall()`.